# Keras beginner question, how to resolve Shapes (None, 6) and (None, 6, 6) are incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am starting out on learning keras and ran into this issue that does not make sense to me. I have a very simple model and I want to pass a trivial data to train on. I want to pass the model two training examples, each 6 elements long, as input. I have two 3 element arrays as labels in one-hot-encoding format. I am getting an error:

`ValueError: Shapes (None, 3) and (None, 6, 3) are incompatible`

I am not sure why this is or if I need to do some preprocessing of the data to be in  a format keras likes. I appeciate any help!

```
finalModel.add(Dense(6, input_shape=(6,1), activation='relu'))
finalModel.add(Dense(3, activation='relu'))
finalModel.add(Dense(3, activation='relu'))
finalModel.add(Dense(3, activation='sigmoid'))

finalModel.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",
              metrics=['accuracy'])
x_train = np.asarray([[0,0,1,0,0,0],[1,0,1,0,1,0]]).astype(np.float32)
y_train = np.asarray([[1,0,0],[0,0,1]]).astype(np.float32)

finalModel.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
```

Comment: Change to `finalModel.add(layers.Dense(6, input_shape=(6,), activation='relu'))`, it should not be (6,1)

Answer (score 0):

Your `x_train` has shape `(BATCH_SIZE, 6)`, so the `input_shape` to your model should be `(6,)`, not `(6,1)`. Try this instead:

```
finalModel.add(Dense(6, input_shape=(6,), activation='relu'))
finalModel.add(Dense(3, activation='relu'))
finalModel.add(Dense(3, activation='relu'))
finalModel.add(Dense(3, activation='sigmoid'))

finalModel.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",
              metrics=['accuracy'])
x_train = np.asarray([[0,0,1,0,0,0],[1,0,1,0,1,0]]).astype(np.float32)
y_train = np.asarray([[1,0,0],[0,0,1]]).astype(np.float32)

finalModel.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
```